# Improving quality of plot with bad numeric performance

Tags: plotting, numerics, integral-transforms

I have a plot which suffers from poor numeric accuracy, any tips on how I can improve the quality of this plot?

```
loss1 = (
  4 s^2 - 3 \[Pi] s BesselI[0, 2 s] + 3 \[Pi] BesselI[1, 2 s] - 
   3 \[Pi] s BesselI[2, 2 s] + 3 \[Pi] s StruveL[0, 2 s] - 
   3 \[Pi] StruveL[1, 2 s] + 3 \[Pi] s StruveL[2, 2 s])/(8 s^2);
loss2 = (Gamma[0, (2 s)/5] - Gamma[0, 2 s])/Log[5];
LogPlot[{loss1, loss2}, {s, 1, 20}, PlotLabel -> "loss after s steps",
  AxesLabel -> {"s"}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"random quadratic", "harmonic decay"}]
```

[image]

Based on asymptotics, the first graph should eventually overtake the second, but I can't plot it far enough to get a sense of how far this is.

This formula was obtained programmatically by calling Laplace transform ([background here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355?p_p_auth=sKZux8nF)), so perhaps I should be doing something different upstream

```
interval[var_, min_, max_] := 
  HeavisideTheta[var - min] - HeavisideTheta[var - max];
{xmin, xmax} = {0, 1};
xvals = Range[xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/10];

icdf[y_] = 
  InverseCDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1], y] // 
   Refine[#, 0 < y < 1] &;
g[x_] = icdf[(1 - x/2)]; (* reverse sort, map 0.5->1 range to 0..1*)
ymin = Limit[g[x], x -> xmax];
ymax = Limit[g[x], x -> xmin, Direction -> "FromAbove"];
gi[y_] = 
  First@SolveValues[{g[x] == y, xmin < x < xmax}, x, 
    Assumptions -> {ymin < y < ymax}];

arg = -D[gi[y], y]*y;
fwd = LaplaceTransform[arg*interval[y, ymin, ymax], y, s] /. s -> 2 s;

loss0 = Asymptotic[fwd, s -> 0];
loss = fwd/loss0 // Simplify;
Print["normalized loss after s steps=", loss];

LogPlot[loss, {s, 1, 20}, PlotLabel -> "loss after s steps", 
 AxesLabel -> {"s"}]
```

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-semicircle-loss-trajectory.nb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use machine precision. Specify a [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html) to use arbitrary-precision.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

loss1 = (4 s^2 - 3 π s BesselI[0, 2 s] + 3 π BesselI[1, 2 s] - 
     3 π s BesselI[2, 2 s] + 3 π s StruveL[0, 2 s] - 
     3 π StruveL[1, 2 s] + 3 π s StruveL[2, 2 s])/(8 s^2);
loss2 = (Gamma[0, (2 s)/5] - Gamma[0, 2 s])/Log[5];

LogPlot[{loss1, loss2}, {s, 1, 20},
 PlotLabel -> "loss after s steps",
 AxesLabel -> {"s"},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   {"random quadratic", "harmonic decay"},
   {0.7, 0.7}],
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]